# Get parent element where multiple child elements have same value in select input

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

I have a multiselect list where values are grouped together by categories

```
    <select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
        <optgroup label="IsStudent">
            <option value="y">Yes</option>
            <option value="n">No</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="IsOffer">
            <option value="y">Yes</option>
            <option value="n">No</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
```

I am using http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/. I am attempting to find the parent of the option element that I select. I do this by:

```
  onChange: function (element, checked) {
            if (checked == true) {
              alert($(element).filter(":selected").parent("optgroup").attr("label"));               
            }
        }
```

When any of my options are selected, it alerts "IsStudent" even if I select the option under "IsOffer". if I change the values to be unique, the alert  alerts the correct parent.

Is it possible to detect the selected element regardless of whether my values are duplicate. I was hoping that it saw it as unique when the parent optgroup is different.
I have tried

```
alert($(element).filter(":selected:last").parent("optgroup").attr("label"));
```

Comment: why was this down voted? It was a legitimate question

Comment: Don't get it either. *le vote up*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$("select").find("option:selected").last().closest("optgroup").attr("label")
```

test on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TwCqp/3/).

if you want to accept this solution, consider to accept sudhar's solution instead, as he was the first to psot the main issue (he should add the `last()` method call, of course).

**edit**:
the op actually wanted the most recently selected item reported. this one does the trick:

```
$("select").click( function(eve) {
    alert($(eve.target).closest("optgroup").attr("label"));
});
```

test on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TwCqp/7/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't work with if I select multiple options

Comment: @mjroodt sure it does! try the fiddle - it shows the optgroup of the last selected item after each change to the selection. i have also edited the fiddle (you are sure you use mine instead of the original ?)

Comment: in the fiddle example I select an option in isOffer. The alert comes up correctly. I hold the ctrl key and select an option in isStudent and the alert comes up as isOffer.

Comment: @mrjoodt so you should update the wording of you question as it can be read as 'reporting the last selected item in the list of available options' instead of 'reporting the most recently selected item'.

Comment: Thanks maybe I could have used better wording but 'Last' meant the last element that I selected. Not the last in the list.

Comment: @mjroodt no problem - i've had my share of ambiguous phrasing ... ;-) have a look at the updated solution which does what you want.

Comment: @downvoter, would you be so kind as to tell about your reason ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select").find("option:selected").closest("optgroup").attr("label")
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TwCqp/)

Comment: this also returns the first optgroup with selcted elements only !

Comment: who would upvote a solution which does not work ? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use [is method](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to know that selected option is last or not:

```
alert($(element).filter(":selected").is(:last).parent("optgroup").attr("label"));
```